# Include Path in vscode not working for c and cmake

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, cmake, include-path

I have following folder structure on my project :

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── common
│   └── packet.h
├── README.md
└── src
    └── main.c
```

In this structure I wanna include `common/packet.h` on `src/main.c`.

main.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "common/packet.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

packet.h:

```
#if !defined(PACKET_H)
#define PACKET_H

#define test 123

#endif // PACKET_H
```

But I get error for including `#include "common/packet.h`.

I can compile this file with following command :

```
$ cc -o src/main.c -I.
```

And I know that i should add its path to `c_cpp_properties.json` :

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/home/ali/programming/c/socket/2/init-udp/1/"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I tried to include this path but its not working for me.

[image]

Anyway how can I fix my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add this line of code on `CmakeLists.txt` file:

```
include_directories(./)
```